# URL Encoding with OkHttp in Java

Tags: java, url, encoding, parameters, okhttp

I'm currently implementing a project that is calling some web services and I am using [OkHttp version 2.7.5](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.okhttp/okhttp/2.7.5)

Part of my project is to transfer data from one endpoint to another, meaning authenticating and fetching data at one end and then authenticating and posting/putting it to another.
When fetching data from one specific endpoint, I first have to request the data that I want. The endpoint then returns a "result set" token. In a second call, where I submit this token as a query parameter, I then get the actual data.

This is now where my issue comes up:

The token that I receive sometimes contains special characters, such as a "+". This unfortunately is then creating an issue, as the HttpUrl object that I create always encodes this as "%20". This changes the token and the data cannot be fetched anymore.

Here is how I basically have done it:

```
    String url = "https://myhost.azure.com:444/api/v1/object?resultSet=FYBGDD4eDan7aHbTGYruWR0OUBvKU9vgLxnf+4tuKRa7J1fn+QC9TZ9sKjfQA46xD8/4CglY0AuGwNhF12Hmw==";
    myLog.info("1.:" + url);

    HttpUrl theURL = HttpUrl.get(URI.create(url));
    myLog.info("2.:" + theURL.toString());
```

This is how the output looks like:

```
17:42:55.651 [main] INFO  basics.ws.App - 1.:https://myhost.azure.com:444/api/v1/object?resultSet=FYBGDD4eDan7aHbTGYruWR0OUBvKU9vgLxnf+4tuKRa7J1fn+QC9TZ9sKjfQA46xD8/4CglY0AuGwNhF12Hmw==
17:42:55.661 [main] INFO  basics.ws.App - 2.:https://myhost.azure.com:444/api/v1/object?resultSet=FYBGDD4eDan7aHbTGYruWR0OUBvKU9vgLxnf%204tuKRa7J1fn%20QC9TZ9sKjfQA46xD8/4CglY0AuGwNhF12Hmw==
```

As you can see, both URLs are not the same. I'm kind of certain that I am just making a stupid encoding mistake, but I've simply not found the solution here.

I also tried to built the whole HttpUrl by myself, but this also didn't work:

```
    HttpUrl theURL2 = new HttpUrl.Builder()
            .scheme("https")
            .host("myhost.azure.com")
            .port(444)
            .addPathSegment("api")
            .addPathSegment("v1")
            .addPathSegment("object")
            .addEncodedQueryParameter("resultSet", "FYBGDD4eDan7aHbTGYruWR0OUBvKU9vgLxnf+4tuKRa7J1fn+QC9TZ9sKjfQA46xD8/4CglY0AuGwNhF12Hmw==")
            .build();
    myLog.info("3.:" + theURL2.toString());
```

Output (with before mentioned code to see the difference)

```
17:55:21.856 [main] INFO  basics.ws.App - 1.:https://myhost.azure.com:444/api/v1/object?resultSet=FYBGDD4eDan7aHbTGYruWR0OUBvKU9vgLxnf+4tuKRa7J1fn+QC9TZ9sKjfQA46xD8/4CglY0AuGwNhF12Hmw==
17:55:21.866 [main] INFO  basics.ws.App - 2.:https://myhost.azure.com:444/api/v1/object?resultSet=FYBGDD4eDan7aHbTGYruWR0OUBvKU9vgLxnf%204tuKRa7J1fn%20QC9TZ9sKjfQA46xD8/4CglY0AuGwNhF12Hmw==
17:55:21.866 [main] INFO  basics.ws.App - 3.:https://myhost.azure.com:444/api/v1/object?resultSet=FYBGDD4eDan7aHbTGYruWR0OUBvKU9vgLxnf%204tuKRa7J1fn%20QC9TZ9sKjfQA46xD8/4CglY0AuGwNhF12Hmw%3D%3D
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this:

```
HttpUrl theURL = HttpUrl.get(URI.create(url));
```

With this:

```
HttpUrl theURL = HttpUrl.get(url);
```

Converting to a URI and then to a HttpUrl isn't the same because URI is very aggressive (and incorrect) about escaping.

Comment: Hi Jesse, thanks for that input! Am I missing something or is there no get(java-lang.String) method from HttpUrl? At least I get the error message:
[ERROR]     method com.squareup.okhttp.HttpUrl.get(java.net.URL) is not applicable
[ERROR]       (argument mismatch; java.lang.String cannot be converted to java.net.URL)

Comment: You should update to at least 3.12.13 if you can, preferably 4.9.1.  Some of these might have been added since OkHttp 2.